# Highcharts - tooltip time value does not match xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with a area chart that I have created.

The time in the tooltip does not correspond with the time on the xAxis (se image for example)

The time in the toolstip is right, the xAxis is however shifted two hours behind in time.

**Settings for the chart** (modified for brevity)

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          tooltip: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day:"%A, %b %e, %Y, %H:%M"
                },
            formatter: function() {
              var tt = '',
                newDate = new Date(this.key).toLocaleString();

              tt = '<b>' + newDate + ':</b> <br/>' + '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>' + ': ' + this.y;

              return tt;
            }
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
          }
        });
```

This is how I draw the series:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
            chart.series[0].addPoint([newValue[i].tValue, newValue[i].value], false, false);
          }
```

**newValue[i].tValue** is in epoch, for example *1493097600000*

[image: xAxis does not correspoeng with tooltip]

Comment: Is your timezone offset +0200 by chance? I.e. one is CEST and one is UTC? Oh, "1493097600000" is not "*in epoch*, it's an offset in milliseconds since the epoch (which was 1970-01-01 so it represents 2017-04-25T05:20:00.000Z).

Comment: try to use [useUTC:false](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global)

Comment: @Deep3015 I have tried that but no success :/

Comment: @RobG Yes, I have suspected it being related to time zone differences, thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case setting useUTC to false helped.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```